Is random slope meaningful when the relevant fixed effect is not significant?
I am building a liner mixed model with the following syntax:
$$
y \sim \text{run} + (1 + \text{run} \mid \text{subjects})
$$
The summary is as follows:

The fixed effect of $\text{run}$ is not significant.
I was wondering then whether the random slopes of $\text{run}$ of different subjects is meaningful. I want to use these slopes of different subjects to correlate with other subjects traits.


What Shawn said, but in general random slope can very well be meaningful when the corresponding fixed effect is non-significant. It can show that the effect size and/or direction differs between subjects (/clusters). However, in these cases random slope variance is usually substantial, unlike in your output.

Thanks. Good to know that random slope can be meaningful when the fixed effect is non-significant. And yes, my slope variance is not significant.

Can you please edit your question to include the images in a text-based format? Images are bad for accessibility (screen readers etc.)

These random slopes are nearly identical and the variance for your random slope is super small. I think you could just omit the random slope and do random intercepts, fixed slopes

The p-value isn't the major concern here...its the perfect negative correlation of random effects, which is a major sign the model is wrong. As you noted, there are miniscule differences in random slopes, which is the most likely culprit. You could instead apply a more parsimonious mixed model which only includes random intercepts, as maximal models (with correlated slopes and intercepts) often have difficulties converging anyway for this very reason.

Thanks! Yes, you are right. It seems that the biggest problem is that the variance is about 0.

I would simply fit the model to be this then: y ~  run   +  (1 |subjects).

Okay ~ It works!
